# squarespace opensource clone / features in ruby on rails?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, content-management-system, frontend, inline-editing

Ive searched extensive but could not find anything that implements squarespace.com features only some blog posts on individual components like inline editing

What I want to build is a very simplistic version of squarespace with

- editing inline content
- changing color or page
- easy add some pages
- all frontend editing

Is there some open source rails app that implements these principles to take a peek at and learn from?

Comment: You ever find anything? I'm right there with you and am considering a project of my own to fulfill this need, for a number of reasons.